# CSS Help Needed with Positioning and Wrapping Elements

Tags: css, position, wrapper

I'm currently building a mobile application using jQuery Mobile but hit the wall due to lacking a understanding of CSS.

I need a bit of help with styling the middle section of the prototype, which i presume consists of multiple divs that overlap each other with usage of relative and absolute positioning.

Should I start off with a wrapper to contain the image of Donald Trump and introduce other divs to position over the image? With all of the divs in place, do I group them together so they have a consistent look across any mobile devices? if yes, how? I would appreciate it if someone can explain, with CSS code, how to achieve the styling shown in the prototype.

[image: A link to the prototype]

Comment: this help? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NdaqPJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course there are several options for achieving the particular look your are aiming for. This is a possibility, which takes advantage of:

- the use of specific html tags for sections (such as `<article>`, `<header>`, etc), rather than generic divs, which is encouraged.
- the handy `::after` css selector, which allows you to append something programatically to existing elements directly from css. In this case, the black square.
- relative positioning of elements with `position: relative`. This allows you to move the article section up relative to its "normal" position so it overlaps with the image.
- width defined as percentage, with `width: 90%`, ensuring the article that overlaps with the image is always slightly thinner, to achieve the desired look.
- the `translate` css property, which allows you to shift the black square by 50% of its own width, so it's perfectly centred (without the translate property, the left side of the black square would be centred, instead of the centre of the square being centred).

I encourage you to play around with the example below to get a feeling for the impact every css rule has on the layout.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  background: white;
}
.image {
  margin-top: 10px;
  background: url('https://fortunedotcom.files.wordpress.com/2017/01/trump2_thumb.jpg') top center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 250px;
}
.image_overlap {
  border-top: 5px solid red;
  padding-top: 40px;
  position: relative;
  top: -40px;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: white;
}
.image_overlap:after {
  content: '1';
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Top Stories</h1>
  <h2>from the world of evil</h2>
</header>

<main>
  <div class="image"></div>
  <article class="image_overlap">
    <p>#AMERICA</p>
    <br>
    <h3>How the WWIII <br>Took Place Last Night</h3>
  </article>
</main>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. With the :after css selector, now I can bring more coherence and readability to my code. Here's a couple more questions. Is it unnecessary practice to add to the class of image such a code: position: relative;? What are the advantages of setting box-sizing to border box at the very beginning?

Comment: You don't need to add **position: relative** to the image class in this case, since you won't be using it to move the image relative to the position it's in now. As for setting **box-sizing**, that's simply a decision that defines how border and padding values are taken into account. It's not necessary to use border-box here, it's more a question of preference. You can read more about it here: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/box-sizing-secret-simple-css-layouts